# When was the 74HC595 designed?

Tags: digital-logic, history

I was looking at some classic logic IC:s like the 74-series and could not help to wonder when they where designed, since it feels like they have been around a very long time.

If we take a example, how old is the [74HC595](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT595.pdf) design?

Comment: We've had a few questions like this before, about the history of parts/standards. They were all closed, so this may also happen to your question.

Comment: To answer your question: it's old. I found traces of the 74595, that's even from before LS-TTL. Might be mid-70s.

Comment: Very interesting.

Comment: I don't think it's before LS TTL became common.  My second edition of the TI TTL databook from 1976 lists many LS parts, but no mention of the '595 in any form.

Comment: @Olin - still, odd that they also released it in TTL, which didn't have any advantages over LS-TTL. Would there have been other new TTL devices released after LS-TTL became available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fourth Edition, 1980, of TI's "The TTL Data Book for Design Engineers" (*the* TTL reference at the time!) doesn't list the 595.
I found references to the original TTL 74595 (pre-LS) on the 'Net, though. Probably will be from well before 1980, the Data Book already contains many LS-TTL ICs. It's old.

Note:
I've advised here before against using the 74HC595 to drive LEDS: 8 LEDs @ 20mA/LED exceeds the maximum device current of 70mA. The original 74595 may not have been used to drive LEDs, they weren't that common mid-70s. I remember seeing 7-segment displays in a Radio Shack (Tandy in Belgium) catalog at the time, which used electric filaments instead of LEDs. That was already in the same housing the LED displays use, not a tube.

Comment: @Johan - Thanks for the accept. Your next question may be: how long back dates LS-TTL? ;-) I don't know, I know the first TTL ICs appeared 50 years ago.

Comment: I figured since you did answer the question and since the question is about to be closed I better hurry and accept ;)

Comment: One thing that is cool is that some of those 74 IC:s still is in use in some places, I mean how many of the modern MCU:s will be around 30-40 years from now.

Comment: @Johan - I don't think a closed question will stop you from accepting an answer. I guess I upvoted closed questions too. It just means no new answers are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_family), the HC logic family was only introduced in 1982.
Whether the '595 was part of the original roll-out, I couldn't say, but the specific part you called out couldn't have been developed before that time.

Comment: I interpreted it differently. To me the design of the HC595 and the 74595 are the same. Functional diagram is the same. It's just the technological implementation that's different.

Comment: @stevenvh, your interpretation is reasonable; But OP asked specifically about the "74HC495" and I thought especially the link to the WP article naming the introduction dates of the various families was relevant.

Comment: ...and anyway the 74595 was probably just a new technological implementation of an RTL part. And the RTL part was just a new technological implementation of a tube circuit ...

Comment: Would it? I guess the real growth of the number of different devices only started with TTL. I think many/most TTL parts, especially not the more complex, were ever released in RTL/DTL. Just guessing.

Comment: @stevenvh, you're right --- maybe there wasn't an RTL shift register IC... But it would have been a common circuit to build from less complex chips, or to build as a subassembly from discrete transistors and resistors.

Comment: "were ever" should be "were never", obviously :-/

Comment: I would be surprised if there wasn't an RTL serial-in parallel-out shift register of some sort, but would not be surprised if the only way to get a shift register whose outputs wouldn't change until shifting was complete would have been to combine a '164-style shifter with a '373- or '374-style latch.